# Nordlynx-protocol connection to Nordvpn within network namespace

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, nordvpn

I'd like to create a Nordlynx connection to Nordvpn within a netns.
I understand that starting an OpenVPN-protocol connection to Nordvpn within a netns using OpenVPN is very straightforward, but I'd like to use the performance bump from the Nordlynx protocol.

AFAIK the only way to initiate a Nordlynx connection is with the Nordvpn executable.

First attempt: create a simple netns (named `mynetns`) and populate it with loopback and macvlan link (named `mv-eth0`) to my internet-connected interface (`eth0`, in default network namespace) with a default route to allow internet access from `mynetns` via `mv-eth0`.  Now run:

```
sudo ip netns exec mynetns nordvpn connect <somewhere>
```

This happily executes, but the Nordvpn interface (named `nordlynx`) that is created by `nordvpn` is in the *default* network namespace, not `mynetns` as expected.  Furthermore, `nordvpn` adds rules to the iptables in the *default* network namespace.  It's possible to manually move the `nordlynx` interface and rules to another netns, however, to then interact with that `nordlynx` interface (to reconnect etc.) it must be returned to the default namespace then shifted back after the interaction.  Very clunky.

Is it "normal" for a process to be able to opt-out of a nominated network namespace like this?

Second attempt: Using the same simple netns descibed above, "jail" a user (`myuser`) within `mynetns` (see https://github.com/sebasth/pam_netns) then use `myuser` to connect:

```
sudo -u myuser nordvpn connect <somewhere>
```

or login as `myuser` and run:

```
nordvpn connect <somewhere>
```

Again this happily executes, but the results are identical to above - the `nordlynx` interface is created in the default network namespace.

I assume this is a textbook case for using Docker or similar, but I'd like to know if there's anything else I should try before going down the full-blown container route.

Nordvpn's help-desk state:

> the set-up you are trying to do here is outside of our knowledge or
> assistance scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't investigated yet, but I strongly suspect that it's not `nordvpn connect` that actually creates the interface – it's done by a daemon/service that's *already running* within the initial namespace, and which the `nordvpn` tool contacts remotely. This is a common design pattern for programs that need root privileges to do their job, yet also need to be run as a regular user, especially for GUIs.

(It's like how systemctl doesn't actually start anything itself, but asks systemd to start the service.)

Look in `systemctl -t service` for the NordVPN daemon and see if you can configure it to run in your existing namespace.

Comment: You're quite right, Nordvpn runs a `nordvpnd` daemon.  If (continuing my example above) you start it as:

`sudo ip netns exec mynetns nordvpnd`

then create a VPN with:

`sudo ip netns exec mynetns nordvpn connect <somewhere>`

the `nordlynx` interface will be created in `mynetns` and expected.
Thank-you @user1686!

Comment: @mike what version of nordvpn are you using? when I tryed executing the nordvpnd inside the namespace, it cannot create the socket file as I get the error: Error on listening to UNIX domain socket: listen unix /run/nordvpn/nordvpnd.sock: bind: no such file or directory.

Comment: @RenatoSz: You need to pre-create the directory for it to put the socket in. (Use tmpfiles.d to automate that.)

Comment: @RenatoSz: I'm currently using nordvpn 3.17.2
Take a look at how Nordvpn works in a standard (non-netns) install: on my (Debian/Systemd) device, a systemd service (`nordvpnd.socket`) creates the socket that is missing in your setup.  The successful completion of that service then triggers the nordvpnd daemon via the `nordvpnd.service`.  Once the nordvpnd daemon is happily running you should be able to create a tunnel using the `nordvpn` command-line tool.